# Query to get all those names of employees,who have 'A' as their middle character in their name

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

E.g:- BRAKE,CRANE etc.

In my employees table , I have `ENAME,ENO,JOB,SALARY`.

Here, I want to extract out those enames that have an 'A' as the center character in their name.

If length of ename is odd,then center one, so i need to detect odd and even position in ename.

So, I tried this, but stuck up ,so can i expect a help from  here?

```
SELECT ENAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE A IN
(SELECT ENAME,
       SUBSTR(ENAME,LENGTH(ENAME)/2+1,1)
FROM EMPLOYEES)
;
```

Comment: What happens when `ENAME` is has an even length, do you still want to detect the 'a'?

Comment: yes, as even won't have a exact middle, so near to it

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: WHY QUESTION IS DOWN VOTED,WHATS WRONG WITH THAT

Comment: @Demla - I'm guessing for all the caps in the original version

Comment: @Demla Pawan - I believe that people were punishing you for writing your question without formatting and all in caps. A very childish thing to do, if you ask me.

Comment: @LAMAK even I thought so, however they may be enforcing sites rules by down voting like that

Comment: @Demla Pawan - Don't worry, in any case, upvotes weight more than downvotes ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for odd length strings, which I think is what you wanted. Next time please don't use caps like that. It took me 5 minutes just to read your post.

```
SELECT `ENAME` FROM  `EMPLOYEES` WHERE SUBSTR(`ENAME`, LENGTH(`ENAME`)/2+1, 1) =  'A'
```

Comment: I figured out, is like same as yours , along with: OR SUBSTR(ENAME, LENGTH(ENAME)/2, 1) =  'A'

Comment: That depends, for even do you want the ENAME to have two A's like `bAAb`, or would you also accept the string `bAbb` and `bbAb`?

Answer (score 1):

This checks first that they have an odd number of letters in the name, then does the check.

The second part checks the middle 2 letters for even-numbered lengths to see if either is A.

This is SQL Server syntax but I think Oracle should be similar.

```
SELECT ENAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE ((LEN(ENAME) %2) = 1
AND SUBSTRING(ENAME, LEN(Ename)/2+1, 1) = 'A')
OR
((LEN(ENAME) %2) = 0
AND SUBSTRING(ENAME, LEN(ENAME)/2-1, 2) LIKE '%A%')
```

Comment: I don't think your second substring is correct.  For a six-character string, wouldn't it return the first two characters instead of the middle two?  Unless string indexing starts at 0, but even then I think it wouldn't be right.

Comment: +1, Yes, just changing `LEN(ENAME)%2` for `MOD(LENGTH(ENAME,2))` should do it

Comment: @DAve No you're right, it should be -1 not -2.  I'll correct.  Good eye.

Comment: this may not work in oracle,by the way, what database you run this

Comment: I mentioned in the answer it's for SQL Server.  You will need to make changes to the functions as indicated by Lamak.

Comment: SORRY @JNK, AS IM A NEWBIE, I MAY NOT HAVE A KEEN EYE

Comment: Demla - no problem, take it easy on the CAPS LOCK THOUGH

Comment: i tried the corrections also by @Lamak, however negative,, So thankyou ALL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ename
  FROM employees
WHERE
INSTR(
CASE
  WHEN MOD(LENGTH(ename),2) = 0 THEN SUBSTR( ename, LENGTH(ename)/2, 2 )
  ELSE SUBSTR( ename, (1+LENGTH(ename)/2), 1 )
END,
'A'
) > 0
```

Comment: thanks man, I know, your solution is most compact, buts its way too high for newbie like me as it involves so  much pl/sql may be.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMPLOYEES where ENAME=SUBSTR(ENAME,LENGTH((ENAME+1)/2),1)
```

What Database service are you using? (for instance in MS SQL server you must use Len)

Answer (score 0):

You may even try this one:

`select ename from emp where substr(ename,ceil((length(ename))/2),1)='A';`

This will work for both even and odd length strings...hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ename FROM employees
WHERE instr(ename, 'A', 1, 1) = round(length(ename) / 2);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, format your code in order to make this more readable by placing 4 spaces before every clause